# ThreadAbortException thrown from Response.redirect not being caught by Application_Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some code that is calling `Response.Redirect` which throws the `ThreadAbortException`. I can see that it occurs in the debugger but the Application_Error method isn't called. The code will continue on if I <kbd>F5</kbd> after it broke on the exception.

If I purposely throw an exception right before the `Response.Redirect`, it will go through the `Application_Error` method.

So I can't figure out why the `ThreadAbortException` isn't being handled the same way. This also is a dilemma with our production site. I can see the `ThreadAbortExceptions` occurring in the dev environment and I expect they are occurring in production, but there is no clue of it. Production runs fine, maybe for the same reason I'm not seeing `ThreadAbortExceptions` handled as I would expect.

If anyone can help with what may be happening, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

`ThreadAbortException` is basically an internal signal to abort a thread. It's a bit special exception - it can't be caught (it will always be automatically rethrown), and it will *not* bring down your application.

In your case, it's caused by your use of `Response.Redirect` - whenever you use the variant that ends the request, it will do this. This is basically to short-circuit the request and get the redirect sent without executing the rest of the request. There are usually better ways to do a redirect, but this doesn't really hurt.

Comment: Thanks, that would certainly explain a lot. I do have code to do the Response.Redirects differently but I had to understand the above behavior before proceeding on the changes.